# UpdatePolicy in AutoScalingGroup failes to update instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have used the following settings in the CloudFormation for creating an autoscaling group:

```
"myautoscalinggroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
  "UpdatePolicy" : {
    "AutoScalingRollingUpdate" : {
     "MinInstancesInService" : "1",
     "MaxBatchSize" : "2",
     "WaitOnResourceSignals" : "true",
     "PauseTime" : "PT5M"
    }
  },
  "Properties": {
    "AvailabilityZones": [
      "ap-southeast-2b",
      "ap-southeast-2a"
    ],
    "Cooldown": "300",
    "DesiredCapacity": { "Ref" : "InstanceCount"},
    "HealthCheckGracePeriod": "300",
    "HealthCheckType": "EC2",
    "MaxSize": "5",
    "MinSize": "1",
    "VPCZoneIdentifier": { "Ref" : "WebServerSubnets" },
    "LaunchConfigurationName": {
      "Ref": "mylaunchconfiguration"
    },
    "LoadBalancerNames": [
      {
        "Ref": "myloadbalancer"
      }
    ],
    "TerminationPolicies": [
      "Default"
    ]
  }
},
"mylaunchconfiguration": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
  "Metadata" : {
    "Comment": "Get web page",
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
      "config" : {
        "packages" : {
          "yum" : {
            "httpd" : []
          }
        },
        "sources" : { 
          "/var/www/html" :  "address to web-site contents"
        },
        "services" : {
          "sysvinit" : {
            "httpd"    : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Properties": {
    "ImageId": "ami-fd9cecc7",
    "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
    "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
      "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
      "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
      "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
         "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
         "         --resource mylaunchconfiguration ",
         "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",

      "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
         "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
         "         --resource myautoscalinggroup ",
         "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"

    ]]}},
    "KeyName": "myKey",
    "SecurityGroups": [{ "Ref" : "mySecurityGroup" }],
    "BlockDeviceMappings": [
      {
        "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
        "Ebs": {
          "VolumeSize": 8
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But the update policy fails to update instances when I update the stack with a new launch configuration. But when I terminate the instances manually, the AutoScalingGroup kicks in and starts new instances with the updated LaunchConfiguration. Any idea on how to get the update policy working?

Thanks

Comment: Before you try to update the launch configuration, are your instances all "InService" and "Healthy"? And you are using `WaitOnResourceSignals` - do you actually signal?

Comment: Yes they are all healthy and in service. I put /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal in mylaunchconfiguration to signal. You can see it in the post.

Comment: Right. I notice nothing obviously wrong here. My suggestion would be to strip this down to the bare minimum, just a plain, simple AMI in a single-node auto-scaling group, and see if it still does not work. If it does you can start adding things back and see where it starts failing.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just followed their [sample](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-west-2/AutoScalingRollingUpdates.template)

Answer (score 1):

The AutoScaling UpdatePolicy will not be triggered by a change to the LaunchConfiguration Metadata.  You will need to make a change to a LaunchConfiguration property to trigger the UpdatePolicy.  The easiest way to do this is to make a simple change to the UserData.